# Include custom geocoding results in mapbox gl as part of a react app

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, geocoding, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to pass a function as the localGeocoder parameter of a mapbox gl geocoder instance ([docs here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#parameters)). I want to do this as part of a react app. The geocoder and map mostly work fine, but I'm not even entering into the function I'm passing when I do geocoding searches. What have I got wrong with this setup?

I know that the localGeocoder function is supposed to return an array of geojson features in the carmen geojson format, but since I couldn't get this to work I just put a console.log() statement in the function and looking at the dev tools in the browser and it's not executing. The main parts of the component are below, but you'll need to fill in your own mapbox accessToken to get it to work. I know that mapbox has a [working example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/forward-geocode-custom-data/) of how to pass a localGeocoder function, but that doesn't use react and I think that's where I'm going wrong here so that example isn't really much help to me.

```
import React from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
import Geocoder from 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';
import 'mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css'
import './map.scss';

mapboxgl.accessToken = ENTER_YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE;    
export class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      lng: -73.9392,
      lat: 40.8053,
      zoom: 15
    };

    this.forwardGeocoder = this.forwardGeocoder.bind(this);
  }

  forwardGeocoder(query) {
    console.log('QUERY:', query);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
      zoomAnimation: false
    });

    const geocoder = new Geocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
      autocomplete: false,
      localGeocoder: this.forwardGeocoder,
      proximity: {longitude: this.state.lng, latitude: this.state.lat}
    })
    
    map.addControl(geocoder);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} className='mapContainer' />
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, i didnt get it quite well.. You are saying that `console.log('QUERY:', query)` doesnt run when you type some search?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto yes that's right. Searching just continues to be the same as without the custom geocoding results.

Comment: Hum.. For me it worked fine. I type a place, it shows into console and the map goes to location. How did you add Geocoder package?

Comment: Yes, the regular geocoding works, but I are you entering into the forwardGeocoder function I defined above? That's what I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: Do you mean the console with the query result? Yes, its working for me (shows the query on the console).

Comment: If my example logs the query in the console for you, then I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,

I did a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/geocoder-test-r5jjr) to you check (just need to add you API Key).

- If you search for coffee, you will see `QUERY: coffee` in console.

So, the only difference from your code to mine is:

- `mapbox-gl-geocoder` import.

You are doing like this:

```
import Geocoder from 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';
import 'mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css'
```

And I'm doing like this:

```
import Geocoder from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder";
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css";
```

As i don´t know how you added the mapbox-gl-geocoder package, i will describe how i did:

I'm using yarn:

`yarn add react-map-gl-geocoder`

If you are using npm:

`npm install react-map-gl-geocoder`

After that, my package.json has this versions:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"mapbox-gl": "^1.3.1",
"@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.7.0",
```

Maybe that could be the issue. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Changing the import statements fixed the issue, thank you!